# Custom change operator using Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I'm looking to create a Combine publisher/subscriber/subscription that behaves like this:

```swift
struct Change<Value> {
  let new: Value
  let previous: Value?
}

let pub = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()

let cancellable = pub
  .change()
  .sink { (change: Change<Int>) -> Void in
    print(change)
  }

pub.send(1) // prints Change(new: 1, previous: nil)
pub.send(2) // prints Change(new: 2, previous: 1)
pub.send(3) // prints Change(new: 3, previous: 2)
```

Having trouble coming up with the right implementation. I've made my own Publisher/Subscription to wrap external API calls and the sort, but can't come up with the right combination when some state needs to be retained, like the previous value in this example (I think this means you need a custom Subscriber?)

An alternate syntax with the same semantics would also be acceptable, if for some reason the `.change()` syntax is unworkable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build the `change` operator out of the `scan` and `map` operators like this:

```
struct Change<Value> {
    var old: Value?
    var new: Value
}

extension Publisher {
    func change() -> Publishers.Map<Publishers.Scan<Self, (Optional<Self.Output>, Optional<Self.Output>)>, Change<Self.Output>> {
        return self
            .scan((Output?.none, Output?.none)) { (state, new) in
                (state.1, .some(new))
            }
            .map { (old, new) in
                Change(old: old, new: new!)
            }
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
let pub = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
let ticket = pub
    .change()
    .sink { print($0) }

pub.send(1)
// Output: Change<Int>(old: nil, new: 1)

pub.send(2)
// Output: Change<Int>(old: Optional(1), new: 2)

pub.send(3)
// Output: Change<Int>(old: Optional(2), new: 3)
```

Comment: Oh dang, how did I miss `scan`! Thank you so much!